# Rails Post comments nested within category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails blog where all posts are nested under categories and now I am adding comments with are nested under posts but the form is throwing `` undefined method `post_comments_path' `` error.

I think I need to make the @posts something like @categories.post but I am unsure.

#### Routes

```
resources :categories do
  resources :posts, path: 'article' do
    resources :comments, :only => [:create]
  end
end
```

#### Controller

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @posts.comments.create!(params[:comment])
    redirect_to @post
end
```

#### View

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, Comment.new ], :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try to run `rake routes`. You will see that the most likely path is: `new_category_post_comment_path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're forgetting categories. You need to either provide a category:

#### Controller

```
def new
  ...
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  ...
end

def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @posts.comments.create!(params[:comment])
    redirect_to @post
end
```

#### View

```
<%= simple_form_for [@category, @post, Comment.new ], :url => category_post_comments_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

or remove categories from the routes like so:

#### Routes

```
resources :posts, path: 'article' do
  resources :comments, :only => [:create]
end
```

Comment: I thought that was the issue but im still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Now I get this error No route matches {:controller=>"comments"} which I don't understand.

Comment: Is params[:category_id]) and params[:post_id] set? Looks like they return nil.

Comment: Yeah, I believe they are set. An id is returned when I type @post.category.id in better errors console.

Comment: How about @category itself?

Comment: I decided there was no need to nest the comments under category and posts so I went with you last idea of just nesting them under posts which works fine :).